# LFTP file prefix while is being downloaded

Tags: bash, lftp

Is it possible to prefix the files that are being downloaded? (similar to rsync)
For instance if fruit_banana is being downloaded, it will show as fruit_banana but the transfer is not completed. (It would be nice to prefix it with something to differentiate between completed or not completed files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually found the answer:

The following extra parameters are needed:

```
set xfer:use-temp-file yes
set xfer:temp-file-name *.lftp
```

Comment: For a prefix, use a different pattern, e.g. .in.*